# ajax response not as intended

Tags: ajax, jquery

The ajax call is established successfully. But when i try to get some response from the php there is a problem. In the .php file i have, `<?php echo 'hello'; ?>`. When i alert the parameter in the success function, it gives me the entire php file. The datatype requested in the ajax call is "text". Please let me know where i am making a mistake..

Code:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function()
{
    /* Attach a submit handler to the form */
    //$("#foo").submit(function(event) {
        $('form').on('submit', function(event){

        /* Stop form from submitting normally */
        event.preventDefault();

        /* Clear result div*/
        $("#result").html('');

        /* Get some values from elements on the page: */
        var values = $(this).serialize();

        /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajaxSamplephp.php",
            type: "post",
            data: values,
            datatype: "text",
            success: function(data){
                alert("success");
                $("#result").html('Submitted successfully');
                alert(data);
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("failure");
                $("#result").html('There is error while submit');
            }
        });
    });
});


</script>


<body>
<form id="foo">
    <label for="bar">A bar</label>
    <input id="bar" name="bar" type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>


<div id="result">RESULT</div>
</body>
```

PHP File

```
<?php
echo 'Hi I am some random';
?>
```

OUTPUT: `<?echo 'Hi I am some random'; ?>` in alert window

GOT THE OUTPUT: My URL was the problem. I use wamp server and Eclipse PDT. The workspace was there in a different location so i coulnt get the output.

And in php file i have given echo `json_encode('[{"key":"value"}]');` In the ajax call, i have changed the data type to `'json'`. But alerting like `alert(data.key)`; gives me '`undefined`' - message. Help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: echo 'Hi I am some random'; exit; ?

Comment: "it gives me the entire php file": What do want to say by that (<?php output as text)?

Comment: exit; is also added to the alert message :(

Comment: What happens when you navigate directly to ajaxSamplephp.php (with your browser)? Your web server seems to do not interpret PHP.

Comment: File download window opens. And the downloaded file has the same output content...

Comment: So you have to install PHP on your web server in order to "execute" PHP files!

Comment: I use Eclipse PDT & WAMP server... The file URL was the problem... Anyways i found the bug... Thanks a lot...

Comment: hi, in php file i have given echo json_encode('[{"key":"value"}]'); In the ajax call, i have changed the data type to 'json'. But alerting like alert(data.key); gives me 'undefined' - message. Please help.

Comment: Try: echo json_encode(array('key' => 'value')); exit;

Comment: Nope... same undefined is alerted. When i alert the entire data, the whole file is shown. But this time, if i open php separately in a web browser, i get {"key":"value"}.

Comment: @Guicara ? could u please help?

Comment: So the JSON seems to be well returned. If you want to be sure, install the Firebug extension in Firefox, then F12, tab "Network" and check JSON. Moreover, write `success: function(data){ console.log(data); }` and check the output in Firebug (tab "Console").

Comment: The json is fine. But i am not able to get the value for the key. So what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE (to answer second part of question):** Do `JSON.parse(data)` to generate a JavaScript object from your JSON.  Then you can use the object returned by the method to get the properties.

---

I'd check to see that your web server is configured to use PHP.

This could mean you have to install the PHP package (using something like `sudo apt-get install php5`) or enable PHP in your web server's configuration (I believe the `libapache2-mod-php5` package on Ubuntu configures it for you).